# How to remove the old "Custom CSS" from customizer after the theme has been migrated to Gutenberg FSE

Tags: block-editor

I had the "Customizer" menu back at some point, and I never figured out what exactly triggered it. I thought it **should** be one of the functions below, but I remember it was not working as expected.

I am using the latest version of Gutenberg and WP 6.0.1.

My issue is there is custom CSS injected into my theme, but I seem to have lost the ability to edit it. Where is it stored in the database. A quick and dirty WP-CLI command to just get rid of it would be enough.

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', __NAMESPACE__ . '\add_custom_bg', 16 );

function add_custom_bg() {

    add_theme_support(
        'custom-background',
        array(
            'default-image'          => '',
            'default-preset'         => 'default',
            'default-position-x'     => 'left',
            'default-position-y'     => 'top',
            'default-size'           => 'auto',
            'default-repeat'         => 'repeat',
            'default-attachment'     => 'scroll',
            'default-color'          => '',
            'wp-head-callback'       => '_custom_background_cb',
            'admin-head-callback'    => '',
            'admin-preview-callback' => '',
        )
    );
}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', __NAMESPACE__ . '\add_custom_header', 15 );

function add_custom_header() {

    // Adds support for WordPress' "custom-header" feature.
    add_theme_support(
        'custom-header',
        array(
            'default-image'          => '%s/src/img/header.jpg',
            'random-default'         => false,
            'width'                  => 1920,
            'height'                 => HEADER_IMG_HEIGHT,
            'flex-height'            => false,
            'flex-width'             => false,
            'default-text-color'     => '',
            'header-text'            => true,
            'uploads'                => true,
            'wp-head-callback'       => '',
            'admin-head-callback'    => '',
            'admin-preview-callback' => '',
            'video'                  => false,
            'video-active-callback'  => 'is_front_page',
        )
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The CSS is stored in the Custom Post Type 'custom_css' and there will be reference to it serialized in the options table with the option_name 'theme_mods_yourthemename' and it will look something like this:

```
s:18:"custom_css_post_id";i:85;
```

The "85" in this example is the post ID of the custom_css post.

An action will remove the CSS option from the customizer.   So you could search for "$wp_customize->remove_section" to find that in your code to reverse the hiding. ([Wordpress Code Reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_customize_manager/remove_section/))

```
function remove_css_customizer() { 
  $wp_customize->remove_section( 'custom_css' );
}

add_action( 'customize_register', 'some_function_name' );
```